# Firebase Phone Auth is not working in flutter app neither in iOS simulator nor in a real device

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I have been trying and searching various methods to make Firebase Phone Auth to work in my flutter application. (There is an [open issue](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/1102) talking about conflicts between Firebase Cloud Messaging & Firebase Phone Auth, but I am unsure if my issue is related to that. I do use Firebase Cloud Messaging which works perfectly fine.).

**In iOS simulator**, whenever I call `FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber`, my app opens a web page for reCAPTCHA workflow, and returns back to the app. Then I see the error logs like below in `verificationFailed` callback. (It is expected to follow reCAPTCHA flow for iOS Simulator according to [Firebase Phone Auth Doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/phone-auth#enable-app-verification))

```
flutter: Instance of 'AuthException'
flutter: {"error":{"code":403,"message":"Requests from this ios client application <empty> are blocked.","errors":[{"message":"Requests from this ios client application <empty> are blocked.","domain":"global","reason":"forbidden"}],"status":"PERMISSION_DENIED"}}
```

It is suspicious that error message is using `<empty>` as my application name, instead of my real app name (or default firebase app name which is __FIRAPP_DEFAULT), but I am unsure why that is happening.

**In real iOS device**, whenever I call `FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber`, the app invokes `verificationFailed` callback again and I get the error with `verifyPhoneNumberError` as code and `Token mismatch` as error message. This is happening in both debug build as well as in release build.

I am using following SDK & library versions.

- Flutter SDK = 1.12.13+hotfix.5
- firebase_core = 0.4.3
- firebase_auth = 0.15.4
- firebase_messaging = 6.0.9

Has anyone been able to get Firebase Auth Phone auth working in iOS? I am stuck in this limbo state because I cannot seem to search any info online related to this. I have setup iOS APN, GoogleService-info.plist, Google Cloud Credentials multiple times so far with no luck. (Given that Firebase Cloud Messaging works perfectly fine, I doubt it is an issue with credentials or APN setup.)

Comment: Hey, did you find any solutions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answering my own question since I figured out the root cause.

In Google Cloud Project that is connected to Firebase, I was able to find a set of API Keys that were created by Firebase.

https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials

For each App you define and create in Firebase, a new API key will be auto-created in the API key section. In my case, there was one for '*iOS key (auto created by Firebase)*' and another for '*Android key (auto created by Firebase)*'.

Well, by default, they do not impose any restrictions and you see a yellow triangle next to the key. So I added restrictions to those keys so that they can only be useable in my app. This is done by setting *Application restrictions* with corresponding bundle id for iOS and another app id for Android within each API key detail page.

This restriction was actually the reason that Phone Auth has not been working in my apps. Once I reverted the change back to *None*, I no longer encountered `Token mismatch` or `AuthException`.

Ideally, I should restrict these API keys to my app only, but it seems like my Flutter app is unable to prove its identity/appId/bundleId to google services, and Google had been rejecting requests from my App. This must be why I was seeing `Requests from this ios client application <empty> are blocked.` error message.

For now, everything is working because there is no restriction, but I will need to figure out why my app and its id association is not working as expected sooner than later, so that I can add restriction back.

Comment: In my flutter app, irrespective of restricted/not restricted, there is no change i.e. it same token error